# KL divergence from a family of distributions

Tags: distributions, density-function, entropy, kullback-leibler

The KL divergence between two probability measures $q,p$ is $$KL(q(x)||p(x)) = - \int_{\mathcal{X}} q(x) \log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx.$$

What's the KL divergence between a measure and a set of measures? Intuitively it'd be something like
$$KL(q(x)||P) = \min_{p\in P} KL(q(x)||p(x))$$

but I don't know how we could find the minimizer.

For example, if $P$ = {mixtures of Gaussians}, is there some analytical way to do this?

Comment: It depends on the family but there is no generic solution. For instance, if $P$ is made of Gaussians $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the solution is$$\min_{\mu,\sigma}\log\sigma^2+\sigma^{-2}\mathbb E_q[(X-\mu)^2]$$which leads to $\mu=\mathbb E_q[X]$ and $\sigma^2=\text{var}_q(X)$.